# When can I close my laptop lid during shutdown?

Tags: windows-7, windows, shutdown, lid

After I tell my Windows 7 netbook to shut down, when can I safely close the lid without confusing the computer?  Do I have to wait for it to finish saying "logging off" or "shutting down"?  Can I close the lid the moment I click "shut down"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As soon as the shutdown procedure starts you should be safe to close the lid.

Comment: I think OP knows you *should* be able to. But I've done this before, and it went into sleep mode instead. Upon opening it again later, I discovered it was still on - it came out of sleep mode, then proceeded to finish it's shutdown process.

Answer (score 1):

normally you have to wait for laptop to do a complete shutdown, but you can change this when you click the power options and set what the lid will do when closed (set it to do nothing, that way, it won't hibernate or sleep, it will just do whatever the laptop is doing before you closed the lid (shutdown if your shutting it down, play music when you're playing music with it))

Answer (score 0):

As @Techie007 said, you can do it as soon as shut down is complete, however, you can also reconfigure your settings so that it powers down as soon you shut the lid. This can be done in the power management windows.

Comment: Is this meant to further confuse the question asker? Techie007 states that he can close the lid as soon as he pushes the 'shut down' button (the procedure starts). Now you say (that Techie007 says) that it can be done as soon as the shut down is complete.
Something is not right here...

Answer (score -1):

it depends what your settings are.
there are different variables.

in your control panel, (under power management), if you have set the computer to DO NOTHING upon closing the lid, then its safe to close your computer lid at ANY TIME during the shut down process.

However:
If you have set your computer to SLEEP or SHUT DOWN or HIBERNATE upon closing the lid, then i would NOT recommend to close the lid during the 'shut down process'.
This is because it would 'possibly' initiate a second shut down (on top of the original shut down).
this process is an INTERRUPTION to a process that was already happening.
and while the chance of damaging your windows Operating System is low, there is still a small possibility that your windows did not shut down in the exact way that you expected... (which MAY lead to an issue).